# Ion Navigation Button cannot control Div ng-show

Tags: ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-show

Currently I facing the problem in showing div once I click on the ion-nav-buttons.
Below is the coding.

```
    <ion-nav-buttons side="secondary">
        <button class="sec_button_text button button-icon" style="font-weight:600" ng-click="inputShow = !inputShow">Search</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content style="margin-top:5px;">
      <div style="padding: 10px;" ng-show="inputShow">
          <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
      </div>
    </ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the trigger (button) and the element to be triggered (ion-content) in separate scopes. `ion-nav-buttons` and `ion-content` are directives and they have their own scope so you can't control the `ng-show` from out of scope.

For a solution you will need to set and change the `inputShow` variable in a scope and depending on wether you have the nav-buttons and content in under the same controller it will work straight away or you will need to broadcast/emit the change. There is always the option to bind the `inputShow` in rootScope but it's not the best solution.